# Idiom for not wanting to be seen by someone

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms

Can you say I didn't want to get stuck in someone's eyes when you don't want to be seen by someone? What is the other expression of avoiding seeing by someone or stay invisible?

Comment: Possibly relevant idiomatic expressions (not mentioned by other answerers) include "I wanted to keep a low profile" and "I wanted to fly under the radar."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [English word for when avoiding being seen by people?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270528/english-word-for-when-avoiding-being-seen-by-people/270642#270642)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using *get stuck in someone's eyes* (you can be stuck in a lift or behind your desk but not in someone's eyes), say ***I wanted to stay out of sight*** or simply ***I didn't want to be seen***.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds very unnatural and not idiomatic. Possible alternative idioms:

**keep under the radar** (very informal, won't find it in most dictionaries):

> doing something without other people noticing.
>   A: Wow! What does her father think?
>   B: Well, we’re keeping our relationship under the radar because we don’t want him to know.
>   [Idiom meanings](http://www.idiomeanings.com/under-the-radar/)

lay low (very informal, colloquial, and technically incorrect grammatically):

> 1. To keep oneself or one's plans hidden.
>      [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lay+low)

"Lie low" would be grammatically correct, buy "lay low" to stay out of sight is more commonly heard in my opinion.

Comment: "On the down low" as well maybe?

Comment: @Chromane "on the down low" has very different connotations in some communities (check Urban Dictionary if you don't mind strong language).

Answer (score -1):

**steer clear of**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/steer+clear+of)

> Stay away from, avoid

As in:

> I was hoping to steer clear of his family at our friend's funeral.